# Checking if rectangles intercect only working if they intersect on first check

Tags: java, android, game-engine, intersection, rectangles

```
public void update() {
    speedY = bg.getSpeedY() / 2;
    tileY += speedY;
    r.set(tileX, tileY, 50, 48);
    // Collision with cycle here:
    if (tileY > 480) {
        r = null;
    }
    if (tileY < 480) {
        checkCollision();
    }
}

private void checkCollision() {
    if (type != 0) {
        boolean val = Rect.intersects(Cycle.rect, r);   
        if (val) {
            test = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the debugger I determined that all the Rectangles are updating correctly, and the Cycle.rect returns the correct rectangle location.  If the rectangles are intersecting on the very first check it works fine. However, as the update runs the intersects never returns true.  Why  might this be happening? I used the boolean val only to help in debugging.

I Logged two values where I believe the rectangles should be intersecting but is not:

r:           02-24 23:32:50.762: V/Rect(16624): Rect(50, 314 - 50, 48)
Cycle.rect:  02-24 23:32:50.762: V/Rect(16624): Rect(49, 329 - 100, 100)

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer with only this information. Maybe `type` is 0? Maybe `Cycle.rect` really doesn't intersect with `r`? Check each position of `Cycle.rect` and `r`. Also, logging the value `tileY` may help.

Comment: Rather than logging the tileY I logged the two rectangles to make sure they do intersect.  I logged inside of the type check so I know the type is not 0.  

02-24 23:32:50.762: V/Rect(16624): Rect(50, 314 - 50, 48)
02-24 23:32:50.762: V/Rect(16624): Rect(49, 329 - 100, 100)

these two rectangles should intersect?

Comment: Check my answer. After experimenting a bit, if I swap your top-bottom values, I get your `Rect`s intersecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on the coordinate system in Java, where top-left is considered as 0. Therefore, a `Rect` is "defined" if `top` coordinate is **less** than `bottom`. Otherwise, it's considered as empty.

From [Rect API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html),

> Note: most methods do not check to see that the coordinates are sorted correctly (i.e. left <= right and top <= bottom).

Also for `set()` (note: emphasize on mine),

> Set the rectangle's coordinates to the specified values. Note: no range checking is performed, so it is up to the caller to **ensure that left <= right and top <= bottom**.

And `isEmpty()`

> Returns true if the rectangle is empty (left >= right or top >= bottom)

Comment: You rock! I was using top and bottom as a height and width.  That caused all my errors.  Thanks!